# Using dataclasses and dictionaries to solve the "box problem"

Tags: python, dictionary, python-dataclasses

The project is to sort items - using a particular algorithm - into boxes. I am having trouble placing items as values into a given box using dictionaries. My primary problem is that I can't figure out how to retrieve 1 value of a key in a dictionary when it has multiple values. My secondary issue is that I fear that I am overcomplicating my program and creating functions that are unnecessary.

I am having trouble with this function in particular:

```
def roomiest(boxList, itemList, boxDict, itemDict):
    """
    For each item find the box with the greatest remaining allowed weight that can support the item and place the item in that box
    :param boxList: The sorted list of boxes( large to small )
    :param itemList: The sorted list of items ( large to small )
    :param boxDict: Dict w/ boxes
    :param itemDict: Dict w/ items
    :return: If boxes were able to fit all items(1); items in box with individual weights(2); Box name with max
    weight(3); items with their weights that were left behind(4)
    """
    sortedItems = sortLargest2Small(itemList)
    sortedBoxes = sortLargest2Small(boxList)

    for item in sortedItems:
        for box in sortedBoxes:
            itemWeight = keywordSearchDict(item, itemDict)
            boxRemWeight = keywordSearchDict(box, boxDict)
            if itemWeight <= boxRemWeight:
                itemDict[
                    box] =  # Need to add item to box with its weight as well as modify the remaining weight the box 
                            # can hold
```

For context, [here is my code](https://pastebin.com/K7FFDHpT).

This is an example of what the text file would look like: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/x2ij14jE)

Comment: I'm confused, I see you're passing in `boxDict` and `boxList` (same with `item...`), but your comment seems to indicate that `boxList` is contained within `boxDict`?

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner That is correct, boxList is the sorted version of boxDict but without the box names

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for dictionary `.get()` and `.update()`. Hard to tell what the input to your function looks like, but here are some notes:

```
itemDictBox = {}

for item in sortedItems:
    for box in sortedBoxes:
        itemWeight = itemDict.get(item, 0)
        boxRemWeight = boxDict.get(box, 0)
        if itemWeight <= boxRemWeight:
            itemDictBox.update(box)
```

You do have a lot of extra code that you can simplify. If you are storing values in text, you can use `','.join(some_list)` to use comma delimiter, and `some_string.split(',')` to convert back to list.

Functions would perform better without the nested for loops also. It seems like you could just loop through the items or boxes, or just have a dictionary with weight as keys.

Answer (score 0):

If `itemList` and `boxList` are already sorted, you don't need to sort them again. Also, since (as I understand it) `boxList` is just a list of the values of `boxDict`, and `itemList` is just a list of the values of `itemDict`, you don't need one or the other of (`boxList` and `itemList`) or (`boxDict` and `itemDict`).

Dictionaries in Python are by definition unsorted and unsortable. They also aren't particularly suited to reverse-lookups (retrieving a key from a value).

I would also probably have "remaining weight" as the variable for each box, instead of the accumulated weight.

Really the best way to do this would probably to be to build a `class Box()` because the boxes are supposed to be named, and keep track of the items they contain. This code will give you (1) and (4) of your objectives. For (2) and (3) you could create a custom `Box()` class; for that, you might define custom `__lt__`, etc. parameters. You might also be able to use a dictionary if you look into the `sorted()` function; the problem with that is you would then have to look up the dictionary key associated with the smallest value.

```
boxWeight = 50
numBoxes = 5
boxList = [boxWeight for _ in range(0, numBoxes)]
itemList = [1, 10, 5, 25, 8, 74]
print("boxList: {}".format(boxList))
remainingItems = []
itemsRemain = False

for item in sorted(itemList):
  boxList = sorted(boxList, reverse = True)
  if boxList[0] > item:
    boxList[0] -= item
  else:
    print("item: {}".format(item))
    remainingItems.append(item)
    print("itemList: {}".format(itemList))
    itemList.remove(item)

remainingWeight = (boxWeight * numBoxes) - sum(boxList)
print("remainingWeight: {}".format(remainingWeight))

if remainingItems:
  itemsRemain = True
```